# Adding an attribute using XmlWriter

Tags: c#, xml, xmlwriter

I am trying to add the following attribute to a node using an XmlWriter but nothing seems to work, does anyone have any ideas?

```
<news:news>
```

I am trying to achieve the following:

```
 <url>
    <loc>http://www.example.org/business/article55.html</loc>
    <news:news>
      <news:publication>
        <news:name>The Example Times</news:name>
        <news:language>en</news:language>
      </news:publication>
      <news:access>Subscription</news:access>
      <news:genres>PressRelease, Blog</news:genres>
      <news:publication_date>2008-12-23</news:publication_date>
      <news:title>Companies A, B in Merger Talks</news:title>
      <news:keywords>business, merger, acquisition, A, B</news:keywords>
      <news:stock_tickers>NASDAQ:A, NASDAQ:B</news:stock_tickers>
    </news:news>
  </url>
```

Thanks

Comment: That's not an attribute - it's the start of an element. You need to be very precise in your terminology here. Can you post a complete example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: ok, the start of the element with the extra part on the end

Comment: What do you mean by "with the extra part on the end"? Again, a *complete* example would really help. If you're vague with the question, we're just not going to be able to help you. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: I have added it to the description what I am trying to achieve

Comment: Well that's adding a *lot* of elements. So which bit is causing you a problem? Is it really just that you can't get the namespace part to work?

Comment: Right. So again, please post what you've tried. Read the link I gave you before - we shouldn't be having to ask this many questions...

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1a1csew(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following link for how to handle namespaces with the XmlWriter

[Namespace Handling in the XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfche0ka.aspx)

You can manually write out the namespace declaration using the WriteAttributeString method, and then use the [WriteStartElement(String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7579ed08.aspx) overload to associate future elements with that namespace, like so

```
writer.WriteStartElement("root");
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "x", null, "urn:1");
writer.WriteStartElement("item", "urn:1");
writer.WriteEndElement();
writer.WriteStartElement("item", "urn:1");
writer.WriteEndElement();
writer.WriteEndElement();
```

Comment: I cant see anywhere on that page or this code how to achieve the code

Answer (score 0):

```
    using System;
    using System.Xml;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(Console.Out);
            writer.WriteStartElement("root");
            writer.WriteAttributeString("news", "http://www.stackoverflow.com");
            writer.WriteStartElement("news:news");
            writer.WriteStartElement("news:publication");
            writer.WriteElementString("news:name", "The Example Times");
            writer.WriteElementString("news:language", "en");
            // etc
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I did this and got the following error: Invalid name character in 'news:news'. The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name

Comment: thats great but it doesn't work when you have the items inside another node